# LiteSpeed (or apache) rewrite to hide SUBFOLDERS domain.com and www.domain.com from mirror.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, litespeed

I've mirrored a webpage with [httrack](https://www.httrack.com/) (wget doesn't have multi connection)

Problem is this page has resources in two domains at the same time:

1. domain.com
2. [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)

So, my scenario is root folder **/var/www/mirror/** with subfolders **/var/www/mirror/domain.com** and **/var/www/mirror/www.domain.com/**

When you load the mirrored page's index in mirror.com, the url you see is https://mirror.com/domain.com/ but also you're redirected to https://mirror.com/www.domain.com/ as soon as you click in any content (see postdata at the end)

I've managed to hide one of the subfolders when you load the index in /var/www/mirror/index.html (going to mirror.com) with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain.com/$1
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ domain.com/index.html [L]
```

But when I add the same for the second subdomain (www.):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain.com/$1
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ domain.com/index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www.domain.com/$1
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ www.domain.com/index.html [L]
```

the page breaks (error loading stylesheets, resources, etc).

I've tried leaving [L] only at the end, with domain.com in the last RewriteRule but also with [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) in the last RewriteRule, nothing works.

**PS: In the real page**, only index works with domain.com, **as soon as you click in any link, you're redirected forever to browse in [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)**, but I would love to have **my mirror as domain.com always**, even when my mirrored resources are linking to /var/www/mirror/www.domain.com subfolder, if that's possible.

---

Edit to add some examples:

1. When I load **mirror.com**, I want index to be **mirror.com/** and nothing else (this works ok with my first .htaccess example)
2. When I click in any link, mirrored content send me to **mirror.com/www.domain.com/someContent.html**, but I want to see in browser's url **mirror.com/someContent.html**
3. If I load some real subfolder, ie. **mirror.com/www.domain.com/tags/someContent.html**, I want to see in the url **mirror.com/tags/someContent.html**

Comment: With **#2** and **#3** you need to actually change the internal links in the HTML source - you can't do this in `.htaccess`. To remove this part of the URL in `.htaccess` the user will be constantly redirected which is bad for the user (and your server). But even then the _undesirable_ URL is still exposed to the user (and search engines) in the HTML (hover over links etc.).

Comment: So, iframe then... (and of course, to cry in a corner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache mod_rewite can not see the content of the page i.e. it can not alter URL links contained within the page. You could try use Apache mod_proxy_html which can modify URL links contained within the page. See below for further info.

http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/